# tesseract cannot read clear single line

Tags: tesseract

So I have this png image here

[image]

and when I try to read it with tesseract on the command line, I get some random character

```
❯ tesseract Selection_002.png stdout --psm 7
  Warning. Invalid resolution 0 dpi. Using 70 instead.
  ale PR Me)
```

I'm running tesseract version 4.0.0-beta.1-370-g8b64 on ubuntu.
I would have guessed that this image would be easy to read for tesseract?
I've gone through trying to resize the image and "cleaning" it up but there's no much noise to clean on that. What Am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try inverting the image color. (Black text on white).
I tried with your image as well as inverting the color. Both gave successful results.

[image]

Comment: hey thanks for your answer. Could you tell me which version you are running and what you are running on the command line to get the result you have?

Comment: I am currently using Tesseract 4.0.0 in Ubuntu 16.04 Version. The command given was same. However, I read somewhere that black text on white background is preferable.